# Replace the all content starting from (color to ;) and starting ? to )

Tags: python, replace, python-re

this is my code so far:

```
import re
a = ["abc", " this is in blue color","(Refer: '(color:rgb(61, 142, 185); )Set the TEST VIN value'(color:rgb(0, 0, 0); ) in document: (color:rgb(61, 142, 185); )[UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf|CB:/displayDocument/UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf?task_id=12639618&artifact_id=48569866] )"]
p = re.compile(r'(color[\w]+\;)').sub('', a[i])
print(p)
```

Output required:

```
["abc", " this is in blue color","(Refer: 'Set the TEST VIN value' in document: [UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf|CB:/displayDocument/UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf)"]
```

Comment: yes can you please elaborate this

Comment: You could match either the color part or from the question mark until the `)` at the end of the string `\(color:\w+\([^()]*\); \)|\?[^?]+(?=\)$)` https://regex101.com/r/ZU5ti3/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are 3 color parts to remove in the string and the part at the end from the question mark until right before the `)`

You could match all the parts using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`

```
\(color:\w+\([^()]*\); \)|\?[^?]+(?=\)$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZU5ti3/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RVD4nk)

- `\(color:` Match `(color:`
- `\w+\([^()]*\); \)` Match 1+ word chars followed by matching from `(` to `)` a space and another `)`
- `|` Or
- `\?[^?]+` Match `?` and 1+ times all chars except `?`
- `(?=\)$)` Assert what is on the right is `)` at the end of the string

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"\(color:\w+\([^()]*\); \)|\?[^?]+(?=\)$)"
test_str = " this is in blue color\",\"(Refer: 'Set the TEST VIN value' in document: [UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf|CB:/displayDocument/UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf)"
result = re.sub(regex, "", test_str)

print (result)
```

*Output*

```
 this is in blue color","(Refer: 'Set the TEST VIN value' in document: [UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf|CB:/displayDocument/UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf)
```

Comment: please include square bracket in last:                                                                        this is in blue color","(Refer: 'Set the TEST VIN value' in document: [UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf|CB:/displayDocument/UserGuide_Upgrade_2020_W10_final.pdf])

Comment: You could match it instead of using the lookahead https://regex101.com/r/toBtAZ/1